# What is happening in this loose equality comparison of 2 empty arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, coercion

I am struggling with understanding how this snippet works on a basic level

```
if([] == ![]){
    console.log("this evaluates to true");
}
```

Please help me understand where I got it wrong. My thinking:

1. First there is operator precedence so `!` evaluates before `==`.
2. Next `ToPrimitive` is called and `[]` converts to empty string.
3. `!` operator notices that it needs to convert `""` into `boolean` so it takes that value and makes it into `false` then negates into `true`.
4. `==` prefers to compare numbers so in my thinking `true` makes `1` and `[]` is converted into `""` and then `0`

Why does it work then? Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: `![]` is `false`, not `true`, because `[]` is an object. `ToPrimitive` is not called before negation, it’s called at the point of negation, if anything. `==` coerces the first array.

Comment: yes ![] IS false but HOW it works? WHY its false? These are the real questions. The explanation that empty array is an object does not convince me sorry

Comment: @KonradAlbrecht, yet that is the explanation. If you are not satisfied with that, then that is really your problem. In JavaScript *all* objects (except `null` which is not really an object and `document.all`, which is a whole different story) are truthy. There is nothing to understand about that, it is [a given](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). Arrays are objects, and so `[]` is truthy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why does it work then?

TLDR:

```js
[] == ![]
        //toBoolean [1]
[] == !true
[] == false
//loose equality round one [2]
//toPrimitive([]); toNumber(false) [3]
"" == 0
//loose equality round two
//toNumber("") [4]
0 === 0
true
```

Some explanations:

1)

> First there is operator precedence so `!` evaluates before `==`

[Negating something](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.9) calls the internal [`toBoolean`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) method onto that "something" first. In this case this is an Object (as Arrays are Objects) and for that it always returns `true` which is then negated.

2)

Now it's up to [loose equalities special behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) ( see Taurus answer for more info) :

> If A is an Object ( Arrays are Objects ) and B is a Boolean it will do:

```js
ToPrimitive(A) == ToNumber(B)
```

3)

```js
  toPrimitive([])
```

> ToPrimitive(A) attempts to convert its Object argument to a primitive value, by attempting to invoke varying sequences of A.toString and A.valueOf methods on A.

Converting an Array to its primitive is done by calling `toString` ( as they don't have a `valueOf` method) which is basically `join(",")`.

```js
toNumber(false)
```

> The result is 1 if the argument is true. The result is +0 if the argument is false. [Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)

So `false` is converted to `+0`

4)

```js
toNumber("")
```

> A StringNumericLiteral that is empty or contains only white space is converted to +0.

So finally `""` is converted to `+0`

> Where did I get it wrong?

At step 1. Negating something does not call `toPrimitive` but `toBoolean` ...

Comment: Is `ToPrimitive` not involved in parsing `![]`?

Comment: @David Hedlund nope only `toBoolean`

Comment: Operator "==" prefers to compare numbers. That means after step 3 both values are converted to 0 and then compared?

Comment: Indeed, it is as @KonradAlbrecht states, every boolean that is an operand of the loose equality operator `==` will have to be coerced to a number (see my answer). Apart from that detail, good answer.

Comment: @taurus oh no! It looks like ive quoted the wrong row in the table :/

Comment: @JonasW. It is somewhat intricate, so errors like this do happen from time to time.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is not correct (it is now, though), see this example:

```js
if([5] == true) {
console.log("hello"); 
}
```

If everything is indeed processed as the accepted answer states, then `[5] == true` should have evaluated to `true` as the array `[5]` will be converted to its string counterpart (`"5"`), and the string `"5"` is truthy (`Boolean("5") === true` is `true`), so `true == true` must be true.

But this is clearly not the case because the conditional does not evaluate to `true`. 

**So, what's actually happening is:**

 **1.** `![]` will convert its operand to a boolean and then flip that boolean value, every object is truthy, so `![]` is going to evaluate to `false`.

*At this point, the comparison becomes  `[] == false`*

 **2.** What gets into play then is these 2 rules, [clearly stated](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) in #6 in the specs for the Abstract Equality Comparison algorithm:

> 1. If Type(x) is boolean, return the result of the comparison  ToNumber(x) == y.
> 2. If Type(y) is boolean, return the result of the comparison  x == ToNumber(y)

*At this point, the comparison becomes  `[] == 0`.* 

 **3.** Then, it is this rule:

> If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number,
>   return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.

As @Jonas_W stated, an array's `ToPrimitive` will call its `toString`, which will return a comma-separated list of its contents (I am oversimplifying).

*At this point, the comparison becomes  `"" == 0`.*

 **4.** And finally (well, almost), this rule:

> If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number,
>   return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.

An empty string converted to a number is `0` (`Number("") == 0` is `true`).

*At this point, the comparison becomes `0 == 0`.*

 **5.** At last, this rule will apply:

> If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then 
>      
> .........
>         If Type(x) is Number, then
>          
> ......... 
>               If x is the same Number value as y, return true.

---

And, this is why the comparison evaluates to `true`. You can also apply these rules to my first example to see why it doesn't evaluate to `true`.

All the rules I quoted above are clearly stated [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) in the specs.

Answer (score 0):

First, realize that you are comparing two different types of values. 
When you use ![] it results in false. You have code (at core it results in this):

```
if([] == false)
```

Now the second part: since both values are of different type and you are using "==", javascript converts both value type into string (to make sure that they have same type). It starts from left. 
On the left we have []. So javascript applies the `toString` function on [], which results in false. Try `console.log([].toString())`

You should get false on the left as string value. On the right we have boolean value false, and javascript does the same thing with it.
It use the `toString` function on false as well, which results in string value false.
Try `console.log(false.toString())`

This involves two core concepts: how "==" works and associativity of "==" operator - whether it starts from left or right.

Associativity refers to what operator function gets called in: left-to-right or right-to-left.
Operators like == or ! or + are functions that use prefix notation!
The above if statement will result in false if you use "===".
I hope that helps.

Comment: Could you please give reference for your claims?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence                                                                                         https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators        these are two links to mozila developer, which a famous site. And I learned these things in understanding weird parts of js course.

Comment: I mean `javascript converts both value type into string `, `So javascript applies the toString function on [], which results in false`,

Comment: First link I provided discuss that and if you search it more you will find what I'm talking in more details.